# Skip to next iteration in an object for looping

Tags: vba

I would like to start saying that *this question aims to get theoretical background, and not a fix for a specific coding problem*. In other words, I'm asking this only because I would like to learn and get a clear statement "yes, it's possible", "no, it's not possible" that I cannot find anyhow else. Say I have three collection objects:

```
Dim a As New Collection
Dim b As New Collection
Dim c As New Collection
```

I add to them a boolean value into the first position:

```
a.Add True
b.Add False
c.Add True
```

and cast the three inside a fourth collection object:

```
Dim d As New Collection
d.Add a
d.Add b
d.Add c
```

I would like to know how (or if) I can **skip to the next object if a condition is not met**. In *pseudo VBA code* (not executable) I would imagine something like this:

```
For Each coll In d
    'do some stuffs
    If coll(1) = False Then 'if object is false, go to the next object
        Next coll 'not compilable line
    End If
    'do some other stuff if the check has passed
Next coll
```

I have no doubt I might use the so-hated `GoTo` statement to get my result:

```
For Each coll In d
    'do some stuffs
    If coll(1) = False Then 'if object is false, go to the next object
        GoTo NEXTOBJECT
    End If
    'do some other stuff if the check has passed
 NEXTOBJECT:
 Next coll
```

...or I might nest the "if - then" block into a big if statement:

```
For Each coll In d
    'do some stuffs
    If coll(1) <> False Then 'if object is false, go to the next object
        'do some other stuff if the check has passed
    End If
Next coll
```

...which is undoubtedly more elegant than using the GoTo. My question has been asked over and over again into SO, but the problem is that all the (accepted and not) answers are of the kind *how about this?* and not *this is the way* or *this is not possible*. So my question is: **does VBA offer such a statement for this kind of problem, or I should accept the fact that is not possible to jump a set of instructions without a GoTo or without nesting the conditional block in a If statement?**

I add the information (don't know if it's useful or not) that [VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z6zekeaa(v=vs.100).aspx) provides the `ContinueFor` keyword. I have of course looked for the parallel VBA documentation or for the Google -> "ContinueFor for VBA", but nothing is said about it, only "work-arounds" without specifying if it's not possible anyhow else.

Comment: You may review the list of VBA Statements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812(v=office.15).aspx  I do not believe such a thing exists, as you're asking for.

Comment: This is what control block such as `If...Then` are *for*, and your last example seems like the obvious way to do this in VBA. It's not clear what you're looking for here, other than a statement like "continue", which doesn't exist in VBA. And there's nothing wrong specifically with the *careful* use of `Goto`.

Comment: @TimWilliams, this is one of the answers I was expecting to get, thank you. Would you mind writing it as an answer, so I will accept it? i've seen this question over the web but not your answer, it might turn to be a "useful" content for someone in the future wondering as I did today.

Comment: P.s. your answer, I mean "you look for a Continue For statement that doesn't exist in VBA, and the If...then is the way, but GoTo might be carefully used as well".

Answer (score 0):

Use  Functions or Subs to wrap each operation on the collection, avoid trying to jam all of your code into one spot.  It will be easier to maintain in the future.

Your main code:

```
If CheckConditionOnMyCollection(Col1) Then
...
```

Your function:

```
Function CheckConditionOnMyCollection (col as Collection) As Boolean
```

Comment: Thank you Gary, it's a nice tip for sure. But I'm trying to understand if/how is possible to skip the statement, undoubtedly yours is a very useful coding convention but doesn't really answer my doubt :) !

Answer (score 0):

try "continue for"
also as long as you have "if condition" just use that if - endif block but change to if coll(1) = true then.....
I think you'd use the continue or exit more when looping and looking for a value. then when you find it, you stop looking, get it?

```
For Each coll In d
    If coll(1) = False Then 
        CONTINUE FOR
    End If
    process(x)
 Next coll
```

SAME AS

```
For Each coll In d
    If coll(1) = TRUE Then 
            process(x)
    End If
 Next coll
```

Comment: `Continue For` doesn't compile in VBA :)